# bash replace \ with / in a tetxfile

Tags: linux, bash, backslash, slash

I have a file with some file’s path. Like this:

```
C:\Users\peter\workspace\etwas.txt
```

I tried read with this routine

```
while read LINE
do
  web=$LINE
  echo $web

done <etwas.txt
```

The result:

```
C:Userspeterworkspaceetwas.txt
```

I will read in this form

```
C:/Users/peter/workspace/etwas.txt
```

How you can read it?

Answer (score 4):

Try doing this using only *bash builtins*:

```
while read -r LINE; do
  web="${LINE//\\//}"
  echo "$web"
done < etwas.txt
```

### output

```
$ cat etwas.txt 
C:\Users\peter\workspace\etwas.txt
$ while read -r LINE; do
>   web="${LINE//\\//}"
>   echo "$web"
> done < etwas.txt
C:/Users/peter/workspace/etwas.txt
```

I use [bash parameter expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe) to substitute `\` with `/`

Answer (score 0):

The most *portable* way to do this (i.e. *not* relying on bash extensions) is with the [`tr`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/tr) command.

```
tr \\\\ / < etwas.txt | while read LINE
do
    web=$LINE
    echo $web
done
```

(Quadruple backslash?!  Yeah, because *both* the shell and `tr` itself treat backslash as an escape character, so you need to write four of them to get a literal backslash in this context. `'\\'` would also work.)

WARNING: piping input to `while` *may*, but then again *may not*, cause the contents of the loop to be executed in a subshell.